# how to parse this Json in android app?

Tags: android, json, parsing

i want to build a simple app that will fetch records from a remote db and store some records as well
i use php-mysql-apache(wamp) and my php file is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org  /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/json; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
       if (!$link) {
       die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error()); 
    }

    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'greek'", $link); 

    $db_selected = mysql_select_db('products', $link); 
    if (!$db_selected) {
      die ('Can\'t use roflcopter: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $id = $_GET['id']; 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `id` = ".$id. " ORDER BY  `id` ASC";           
    $result = mysql_query($sql); 

    if (!$result) {                 
        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        // $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
        die($message);
    }

     $json = NULL;

      while ($data_array[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 

     $json = json_encode($data_array); 
     }

     echo $json; 

     ?>
     </body> 
     </html>
```

and the response that i take when i run it from the browser is

```
   [{"id":"1590774","name":"Nokia C7","descr":"????. ??????? Symbian 3, ????? 3,5\", 360 ? 640 pixels, Amoled, Capacitive ?????\/???????? 8GB","price":"339","stock":"3"}]
```

(it doesn't recognize the greek caracters - what am i supposed to do?)

What code should i write on eclipse so as to fetch and display that row??

Actually i'm trying to use a project found on the internet as an example which fetches this json array

```
      http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/
```

and the android project consists of 3 java Activities :

```
            public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

        // url to make request
        private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
        private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
        private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
        private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
        private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
        private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
        private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
        private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
        private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
        private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

        // contacts JSONArray
        JSONArray contacts = null;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new       ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

        // looping through All Contacts
        for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
            String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
            String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

            // Phone number is agin JSON Object
            JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
            String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
            String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
            String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
            map.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
            map.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            contactList.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] {
                    R.id.name, R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
            in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });



}
```

}

the second activity is the Json Parser:

```
    public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

and the third one is used to display results to a listview

```
    public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

// JSON node keys
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get JSON values from previous intent
    String name = in.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
    String cost = in.getStringExtra(TAG_EMAIL);
    String description = in.getStringExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);

    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
    TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_label);
    TextView lblDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_label);

    lblName.setText(name);
    lblCost.setText(cost);
    lblDesc.setText(description);
}
```

}

i m trying to change this example to adjust it to my json response, the first thing i realize is that my json array doesn't have any tag like the example's "contacts" tag so as to use it as in the example 
         contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

another thing is that for my app i need to send a parameter to fetch data for a specific id 
i have a table with fields : id, name, desciption, price, stock 
i try my url as 
    "http://localhost/items.php?id=1590774" 
or
    "http://localhost/items.php"

passing the parameter this way

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id","1590774"));
```

im a begginner , so i'd appreciate your help...

Comment: You should share the relevant java code as well, to let us see what parameters did you set for the connection. I think you are missing something like `CoreProtocolPNames.HTTP_CONTENT_CHARSET`.

Comment: i ve edited the question to add the java files of the example i am trying to use

Comment: Not sure, but I believe android by default uses utf_8. If this is true, make sure you send it UTF8_encoded from the server, to the client. If the server sends ???? Then android will recieve ????.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to add a parameter to your `DefaultHttpClient` instance for the character-set to use:

```
...
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.HTTP_CONTENT_CHARSET, HTTP.UTF_8);
// defaultHttpClient
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
...
```

If `HTTP.UTF_8` does not work for you, from the `HTTP` class you can select the appropriate value. 
In case this doesn't solve the problem, please attach some more logcat output.